# where can I find the source code for torch.unique()?

Tags: pytorch

I can only find in the pytorch source code (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/2367face24afb159f73ebf40dc6f23e46132b770/torch/functional.py#L783) the following function call:

`_VF.unique_dim()` and `torch._unique2()`

but they don't point to anywhere else in the directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the pytorch backend code is implemented in C++ and/or CUDA. To see it you need to find the appropriate entrypoint in the source code. There are a couple ways to do this but the easiest I've found without downloading all the code yourself is to search for the keywords on github.

For example, if you go to [github.com](https://www.github.com) and the search for `unique_dim repo:pytorch/pytorch`, then click the "Code" tab on the left side you should quickly find the following.

From [torch/jit/_builtins.py:103](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/dc5cda0cca429a3080f63e7b30b3e87d18df8601/torch/jit/_builtins.py#L103)

```py
 17: _builtin_ops = [
...
103:    (torch._VF.unique_dim, "aten::unique_dim"),
```

From this and further analysis of the code we can conclude that `torch._VF.unique_dim` is actually invoking the `aten::unique_dim` function from the ATen library.

Like most functions in [ATen](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/#aten) there are multiple implementations of this function. Most ATen functions are registered in [aten/src/ATen/native/native_functions.yaml](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b3bb234e16780ea3f3d749d2c8c156c9245eb797/aten/src/ATen/native/native_functions.yaml#L4457), generally the functions here will have a `_cpu` and `_cuda` version.

Going back to the search results we can find that the CUDA implementation is actually calling the function `unique_dim_cuda` at [aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Unique.cu:197](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b3bb234e16780ea3f3d749d2c8c156c9245eb797/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Unique.cu#L197)

```cpp
196: std::tuple<Tensor, Tensor, Tensor>
197: unique_dim_cuda(const Tensor& self, const int64_t dim, const bool sorted, const bool return_inverse, const bool return_counts) {
198:   return AT_DISPATCH_ALL_TYPES_AND2(kBool, kHalf, self.scalar_type(), "unique_dim", [&] {
199:     return unique_dim_cuda_template<scalar_t>(self, dim, false, return_inverse, return_counts);
200:   });
201: }
```

and the CPU implementation is calling the function `unique_dim_cpu` at [aten/src/ATen/native/Unique.cpp:271](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7ee0712642492ef221a69d3fdf13b607f406bd78/aten/src/ATen/native/Unique.cpp#L271)

```cpp
270: std::tuple<Tensor, Tensor, Tensor>
271: unique_dim_cpu(const Tensor& self, const int64_t dim, const bool sorted, const bool return_inverse, const bool return_counts) {
272:   return AT_DISPATCH_ALL_TYPES_AND2(at::ScalarType::BFloat16, at::ScalarType::Bool, self.scalar_type(), "unique_dim", [&] {
273:     // The current implementation using `dim` always sorts due to unhashable tensors
274:     return _unique_dim_cpu_template<scalar_t>(self, dim, false, return_inverse, return_counts);
275:   });
276: }
```

From this point you should be able to trace the function calls further down to see exactly what they are doing.

Following a similar string of searches you should find that `torch._unique2` is implemented at [aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Unique.cu:188](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b3bb234e16780ea3f3d749d2c8c156c9245eb797/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Unique.cu#L188) and [aten/src/ATen/native/Unique.cpp:264](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7ee0712642492ef221a69d3fdf13b607f406bd78/aten/src/ATen/native/Unique.cpp#L264) for CUDA and CPU respectively.