# How can I see source code or explanation of "torch_sparse import SparseTensor"?

Tags: pytorch, sparse-matrix

I am studying some source codes from PytorchGeometric.

Actually I am really finding `from torch_sparse import SparseTensor` in Google, to get how to use `SparseTensor`.

But there is nothing I can see explanation. I saw many documents about COO,CSR something like that, but how can I use SparseTensor?

I read: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html# but there is nothing like SparseTensor.

Comment: I doubt you really want to dig into the implementation too much. It's difficult to follow since most of pytorch is implemented in C++. If you really do want to though, you can find the sparse tensor implementation details at [https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/aten/src/ATen/native/sparse](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/aten/src/ATen/native/sparse)

Comment: Relevant answer if you want to go source diving: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70809901/2790047

Comment: @jodag Wow I appreciate your kind answer... Actually I didn't know what you said because I am not major in CS...

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and stumbled upon your question, so I will just detail what I did here, maybe it helps someone. I think the main confusion results from the naming of the package. `SparseTensor`is from `torch_sparse`, but you posted the documentation of `torch.sparse`. The first is an individual project in the pytorch ecosystem and a part of the foundation of PyTorch Geometric, but the latter is a submodule of the actual official PyTorch package.

So, looking at the right package (`torch_sparse`), there is not much information about how to use the `SparseTensor` class there ([Link](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_sparse)).
If we go to the source code on the other hand ([Link](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_sparse/blob/master/torch_sparse/tensor.py)) you can see that the class has a bunch of classmethods that you can use to genereate your own `SparseTensor` from well documented pytorch classes.

In my case, all I needed was a way to feed the `RGCNConv`Layer with just one Tensor including both the edges and edge types, so I put them together with the following line:

```
edge_index = SparseTensor.from_edge_index(edge_index, edge_types)
```

If you, however, already have a COO or CSR Tensor, you can use the appropriate classmethods instead.